# What to call a correction slip pasted onto a page of a book?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have an old catalogue with new prices pasted in over the old prices. These correction slips are small, only covering the prices but leaving the rest of the page as originally published. What are these slips called? It is not an *errata slip*, nor a *tipped-in page*. Those are different things.

I could continue to call them 'correction slips', but there may be better accepted terminology.

Comment: Seems as if you have come up with the best name.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the term you are looking for is "**cancel slip**."  I have found only two sources that describe such corrections:

The [Bauman Rare Books glossary](https://www.baumanrarebooks.com/rare-book-collecting/glossary.aspx) notes that a cancel may refer to either an entire page that has been replaced, or to "slip of paper pasted over the changed passage," noting that the latter may also be called a "cancel slip."

[The Collation](https://collation.folger.edu/2015/04/correcting-with-cancel-slips/), in an article on cancel slips, shows examples of both large sections of text and small pieces of text being pasted over the original printed material.

Interestingly, the University of Saskatchewan has posted [a fascinating article](http://drc.usask.ca/projects/archbook/corrections.php) on the history of corrections in written documents, and if you scroll down to the section "Corrections in Print," you will find that they describe this process simply as "pasting over the text," reserving the term "cancel" for "a new leaf or sheet that has been printed to replace a section of the text containing errors."  It seems that the term "cancel slip" is not in wide circulation, even among those studying historical printing.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Victoria. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

The word "slip" to me implies that there is a piece of paper included that's intended to replace a page or a portion of a page in the catalog.

If the covering is only for the prices, I would use the word "**tape**" instead of "slip", for example, "**correction tape**" or even "**white out**" (a brand of paint-on correction from the time of typewriters). "White out" can even be used as a verb!